# How to loop through many files using perl oneliner

Tags: perl

I am trying to add a line to many perl files at line 4 using perl liner. I am using :

```
 perl -pi -le 'print "     cell_type = pad;" if $. ==4' *.cell.plt
```

But this is only changing the first file in my directory, not all of them. How do I insert the line in all files at once. I tried several ways but it always fails. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only reading from one file handle, so there's only one line 4. Fortunately, there is a way of resetting `$.`.

```
perl -i -ple'
    print "     cell_type = pad;" if $. == 4;
    close ARGV if eof;
' *.cell.plt
```

(Note that `eof` is different than `eof()`.)

Alternatively, you can execute `perl` for each file

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.cell.plt' -type f -exec \
   perl -i -ple'print "     cell_type = pad;" if $. == 4' {} \;
```

Comment: Thought it might be something like that, but haven't done enough perl one-lining to be sure :)

Comment: @Sobrique, Has nothing to do with "one-lining". I have lots of programs that aren't one-liners that use  `<>`.